# Properties of the Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, analysis, mobius-transformation

I am given four points on a straight line, which are mapped to four points on a circle.  I confirmed that the latter four points are concyclic by calculating their cross ratio, which is real.

Does a Möbius transformation preserve the order of the points on a straight line when they are mapped to a circle?  If so, is it because these transformations preserve orientation?

The question I am looking at is asking me why there is no Möbius transformation with the property that it maps each of the four points on the line to each of the four points on the circle respectively, and I can see that the points on the circle are not in the same order, going around the circle, as the points on the straight line that are mapped to each of them.  Or is there more to it?

PS I can also show that the system of equations does not exist, by forming four equations and substituting in the points, but this seems like a lot of work!

Comment: How are you comparing "order" on a line to "order" on a circle? I would expect "order" on a line to mean a binary relation satisfying the [order axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html), but clearly that is *not* what order on a circle means.

Comment: I see what you are saying and "order" was probably not the right word to use or what I should be thinking of here.  Why would there not exist a Möbius transformation T with the property that $T(2)=6+i$, $T(0)=4+5i$, $T(1)=3i$ and $T(3)=2i$?  I can see that a solution to the system of equations doesn't exist, but is there another way to see it, knowing that the cross ratio is 2, and thus real?

Comment: @user604270 A Möbius transformation is defined by $3$ pairs of points, not $4$.

Comment: I understand, but given that the cross ratio for the four given points is real, some Möbius function must exist that maps a line or circle to the new circle, right?  The questions asks why this specific mapping is not possible, given the four points stated in the comment above.  Or am I missing something?  I'm fairly new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realised that the cross ratio of my original four points is different than that of the four points they are mapped to.  Since Möbius transformations preserve cross ratios, the suggested mapping is not a Möbius transformation.